# How to convert jQuery UI controls to Form element contract?

Tags: html, jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I put slider into form but found it doesn't send it's value as get parameter

https://jsfiddle.net/dimskraft/284x06da/3/

Neither slider `id` not slider value appear in action url. Why and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix it would be to have a hidden input field in the form and update its value based on slider's change event.

Here, I have added input field with name `input1` so you would see that in the final URL. Also, you can assign its initial value with value attribute. I have given `value="0"`

https://jsfiddle.net/fhp81qyb/

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  change: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#input1').val(ui.value);
  }
});

<input type="hidden" name="input1" id="input1" value="0"></input>
```

Comment: Why doesn't slider function generate it automatically?

Comment: The form tag needs to have input tab for values to be sent in URL but looking at the way jQueryUI transforms the slider `div`, it does not create `input` tag so it does not show up automatically.
I don't know for sure why they chose not to add `input` tag but I am guessing they designed it as widget to keep it generic.

Answer (score 0):

Slider is not a form element; hence it is not included in the form data.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/qfbgh0z4/5/

**HTML**

```
<form action="http://localhost" method="get" target="_blank">
  <div id="slider"></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="slider-value" id="slider-value" value="0" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    slide: function(e, ui) {
      $("#slider-value").val(ui.value);
    }
  });
});
```